# When you vote to delete and are capped, you do not regain the lost reputation when you should

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, daily-reputation-limit, vote-to-delete

Like the bug that was on SO where if you lost < 10 reputation when you were capped, you do not regain the delta when you get voted on or off topic, or you get a new follower on your proposals.

Isn't the codebase the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52425/is-the-area51-codebase-the-same-as-sos/52448#52448)

> It's a fork of SOFU, but we are
>   regularly pulling in changes. That
>   particular bug was simply
>   re-introduced, because we changed
>   Down-Mod -> Off-Topic, removed the rep
>   penalty, added it to delete votes, but
>   missed the rep cap correction.