# Is the area51 codebase the same as SO's?

Tags: support, area-51, stackexchange-2.0

I noticed a [few little bugs](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52239/when-you-vote-to-delete-and-are-capped-you-do-not-regain-the-lost-reputation-whe) that had already been fixed here in the trilogy, so I wonder,
Is the area51 a branch from the original code (thus being developed by fog creek instead of Jeff) or is now the team only one, with Jeff participating in the development of SE 2.0, using the SOFU codebase as a starting point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a fork of SOFU, but we are regularly pulling in changes. That particular bug was simply re-introduced, because we changed Down-Mod -> Off-Topic, removed the rep penalty, added it to delete votes, but missed the rep cap correction.  We have it fixed, but it got tangled up in [some pretty major voting changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52168/how-can-we-get-better-quality-on-and-off-topic-questions-in-our-site-proposals/52172#52172) that haven't gone out yet.

The two products aren't and probably will never be a merged codebase because Area 51 is a pretty odd variant of SOFU, and not in ways that would really be useful to abstract out (e.g. questions & answers became proposals & questions, voting changed significantly, neither of which are changes that SOFU will ever want).  Ideally some day we'll abstract out some of the parts that they share, but it's not clear right now how much active development there will be on Area 51 once it's really up and running.