# Area51 user account - copy credentials to all sites not working

Tags: support, area-51, openid

As I was upgrading from MyOpenID to SE_OpenID, I could not get into Area51. On another SE site, I pushed the 'copy credentials to all sites' button, but this didn't work on Area51.

In the end I added the credentials myself, but I guess the bug is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area51 has [separate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52425/is-the-area51-codebase-the-same-as-sos) codebase, so you may need to manually updating login info there for now. And area51 does not have copy login credentials function yet there now.

[image]

Comment: From x.SE to Area51, not the other way around, still fair enough.

Comment: This isn't correct -- though A51 itself doesn't have the "copy login credentials" button yet, clicking the button on other sites pushes credentials to A51 (in theory). We're looking into what went wrong in this specific case.