# Area 51 rep is not displayed in communities list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, top-bar, communities-list

[image]

As you see. What can be the reason? I added it to communities list about a week or two ago.

Comment: @ShadowWizard hallo? Why is it?

Comment: Because the reason is the same: different codebase as explained in the answer to the other question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard While the reason is the same, the problem is different.

Comment: But when the same answer applies to more than one question, they're all duplicates. At least here in MSE. What's the point of repeating the same answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area51 is... *special*. It is being run on a [fork of the Stack Exchange 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52448/140890) platform, but the codebase is so far removed from the current 2.0 codebase used by the rest of the Stack Exchange network that most changes never make it across.

As such, it just doesn't support exporting your reputation for use in that dropdown box.

Once upon a time [a new version of Area51 was in the works](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/next-generation-of-area-51) but the last anyone has heard about that idea was 2 years ago now.

Comment: I suspected that it 1.0. Because no notifications or rep changes are displayed in top bar.

Comment: @nicael: it appears to be based on *really early 2.0 code* instead, I found a developer reference.

Comment: @nicael I believe it's explained pretty well [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211255/152859), by Nick.